# Como estender o comprimento de Widgets dentro de um QScrollArea?

Tags: c++, qt, gui, layout

Estou buscando construir um formulário de perguntas em Qt. Como há várias perguntas a serem respondidas, é necessário permitir a rolagem do formulário, e por isso utilizei uma `QScrollArea`. As perguntas são todas respondidas em uma escala [Likert](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escala_Likert), então eu ajustei o alinhamento do layout que as contém para a esquerda e espacei as opções manualmente. **Ou seja, tudo está alinhado à esquerda**. Também implementei um estilo colorido alternado, apenas para tornar mais agradável para o usuário a diferenciação das perguntas ao rolar o formulário.

Eis a seguir uma imagem do MCVE que eu preparei (e que se encontra a seguir). O principal problema é que eu não consigo fazer com que esse "zebrado" se estenda até o fim do formulário (na direita, indicado na caixa azul na imagem). Há também o espaço que parece uma margem, na esquerda (indicado na caixa vermelha).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resolver o problema principal, eu já tentei alterar as restrições de tamanho dos layouts filhos (usando `setSizeConstraint`) e até mesmo adicionar um alargador (*stretch*) após a última opção (como se pode observar na linha de código marcada com comentário), mas nenhuma dessas opções funciona. E para o problema secundário, bom, eu já tentei alterar as margens via folha de estilos (conforme está no código) e até usar o método `setMargin` da própria classe `QWidget`, mas nada funciona.

O que funciona para o problema principal é definir um tamanho mínimo ou fixo para o container das opções (o objeto em `pRow`), mas eu não posso usar essa opção porque a janela pode ter o tamanho ajustado pelo usuário (ou conforme as dimensões da tela disponíveis a ele). Também porque ele não resolve o problema secundário, e eu não desejaria capturar evento de redimensionamento da janela pra ajustar o tamanho manualmente - já que aí eu perco a vantagem de se usar layouts.

Alguma sugestão?

### Código do MCVE

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QScrollArea>

#define STYLE_SHEET "                               \
                    QWidget#plainArea               \
                    {                               \
                        background-color: #ffffff;  \
                        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;   \
                        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;    \
                        border-width: 0px;          \
                    }                               \
                                                    \
                    QLabel#headerTitle              \
                    {                               \
                        font-size: 25px; }          \
                    }                               \
                                                    \
                    QLabel#questionTitle            \
                    {                               \
                        font-size: 20px;            \
                    }                               \
                                                    \
                    QRadioButton#optionTitle        \
                    {                               \
                        font-size: 16px;            \
                    }                               \
                                                    \
                    QWidget#highlightedrow          \
                    {                               \
                        background-color: #efd3d2;  \
                    }                               \
                    "

QWidget* createQuestionnaire(QWidget *pParent)
{
    QWidget *pQuestionnaire = new QWidget(pParent);
    pQuestionnaire->setObjectName("plainArea");
    pQuestionnaire->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    pQuestionnaire->layout()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);

    // Cabeçalho
    QLabel *pTitle = new QLabel("Por favor, responda às perguntas a seguir.", pQuestionnaire);
    pTitle->setObjectName("headerTitle");
    pQuestionnaire->layout()->addWidget(pTitle);

    QFrame *pLine = new QFrame(pQuestionnaire);
    pLine->setFrameStyle(QFrame::HLine);
    pLine->setLineWidth(4);
    pQuestionnaire->layout()->addWidget(pLine);
    static_cast<QBoxLayout*>(pQuestionnaire->layout())->addSpacing(10);

    // Scroll Area
    QScrollArea *pScroll = new QScrollArea(pQuestionnaire);
    pScroll->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    pScroll->setObjectName("plainArea");
    pScroll->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    pQuestionnaire->layout()->addWidget(pScroll);

    QWidget *pArea = new QWidget(pQuestionnaire);
    pArea->setObjectName("plainArea");
    pArea->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    pArea->layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);

    pScroll->setWidget(pArea);

    // Questões
    QStringList lFruits = {
        "Abacate", "Amora", "Ameixa", "Acerola", "Abacaxi", "Açaí",
        "Banana", "Bacuri", "Buriti", "Butiá", "Bacaba", "Carambola",
        "Cajá", "Caju", "Cereja", "Cacau", "Caqui", "Cupuaçu", "Damasco",
        "Figo", "Framboesa", "Fruta Pão", "Graviola", "Goiaba", "Goiaba Branca",
        "Groselha", "Guaraná", "Grumixama", "Guariroba", "Ingá", "Ibapó",
        "Itu", "Ingá Dedo", "Ingá Branco", "Jaca", "Jabuticaba", "Jambo",
        "Jenipapo", "Jatobá", "Kiwi", "Laranja", "Limão", "Lima Doce",
        "Lixia", "Melancia", "Mamão", "Melão", "Maracujá", "Manga",
        "Macadâmia", "Maçã", "Mangaba", "Mexerica", "Nectarina", "Noz",
        "Nêspera", "Olho-De-Boi", "Pera", "Pêssego", "Pitaya", "Pitanga",
        "Pinha", "Pinhão", "Pitomba", "Pocã", "Quina", "Rabutan", "Romã",
        "Sapoti", "Sapucaia", "Salok", "Saputá", "Tangerina", "Tomate",
        "Tamarindo", "Toranja", "Taiúva", "Uva", "Uxi", "Uvaia", "Umbu",
        "Veludo", "Wampi", "Xixá"
    };

    QStringList lOptions = { "detesto", "gosto pouco", "gosto", "gosto muito", "adoro" };

    for(int i = 0; i < lFruits.size(); i++)
    {
        QWidget *pRow = new QWidget(pQuestionnaire);
        pArea->layout()->addWidget(pRow);

        if(i % 2)
            pRow->setObjectName("highlightedrow");

        pRow->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
        QLabel *pQuestion = new QLabel(QString("%1 - Você gosta de %2?").arg(i+1).arg(lFruits.at(i)), pRow);
        pQuestion->setObjectName("questionTitle");
        pRow->layout()->addWidget(pQuestion);

        QWidget *pOptions = new QWidget(pRow);
        pRow->layout()->addWidget(pOptions);
        pOptions->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());
        pOptions->layout()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);

        static_cast<QBoxLayout*>(pOptions->layout())->addSpacing(60);
        foreach(QString sOption, lOptions)
        {
            QRadioButton *pButton = new QRadioButton(sOption, pOptions);
            pButton->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
            pButton->setObjectName("optionTitle");
            pOptions->layout()->addWidget(pButton);
            static_cast<QBoxLayout*>(pOptions->layout())->addSpacing(20);
        }
        static_cast<QBoxLayout*>(pOptions->layout())->addStretch(); // <--- Stretch não funciona!
    }

    return pQuestionnaire;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication oApp(argc, argv);

    QWidget *pWindow = new QWidget();
    pWindow->setObjectName("plainArea");
    pWindow->setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET);
    pWindow->setWindowTitle("MCVE para o SOPT");

    pWindow->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    pWindow->layout()->addWidget(createQuestionnaire(pWindow));

    pWindow->show();
    pWindow->resize(800, 600);
    return oApp.exec();
}
```

P.S.: Ah, como eu odeio o `QScrollArea` do Qt, viu. rs

Comment: Vou mandar enquadrar, tirar um foto e colocar em todas perguntas que não vão pra frente :)

Comment: Larga a mão de exagerar, vai. :)

Comment: Tá bom, eu não mando enquadrar :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Já descobri como resolver a ambos os problemas.

O problema principal se deve ao fato de que o `QScrollArea` não trabalha bem com uma widget interna que contenha widgets filhas organizadas em layout se não for permitido à widget do scroll ajustar seu tamanho automaticamente. Para isso, basta definir como `true` o valor da propriedade [`widgetResizable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop).

O bacana é que isso **não está nada claro** descrição principal da documentação. Lá na documentação consta apenas o seguinte:

> *The view can be made to be resizable with the setWidgetResizable() function.*

Ao ler isso eu imaginei que o uma widget resizable seria... resizable e portando não precisaria do Scroll! (afinal, como o exemplo da documentação é de imagens, eu imaginei que elas seriam escalonadas para o tamanho do view port **ao invés** de apresentar as barras de rolagem). Mas não, essa propriedade é o que permite que a widget possa aumentar e diminuir de tamanho conforme ela mesma decidir. Honestamente, não entendi o motivo para alguém precisar usar essa propriedade como falso e usar uma área de rolagem, mas enfim...

Para o problema secundário, foi simplesmente mais fácil definir as margens em 0 para todos os componentes via código com o método `setMargin` da classe de layout, e não via folha de estilos.

O código final, que resulta na tela a seguir, é apresentado em seguida.

Tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QScrollArea>

#define STYLE_SHEET "                               \
                    QWidget#plainArea               \
                    {                               \
                        background-color: #ffffff;  \
                    }                               \
                                                    \
                    QLabel#headerTitle              \
                    {                               \
                        font-size: 25px; }          \
                    }                               \
                                                    \
                    QLabel#questionTitle            \
                    {                               \
                        font-size: 20px;            \
                    }                               \
                                                    \
                    QRadioButton#optionTitle        \
                    {                               \
                        font-size: 16px;            \
                    }                               \
                                                    \
                    QWidget#highlightedrow          \
                    {                               \
                        background-color: #efd3d2;  \
                    }                               \
                    "

QWidget* createQuestionnaire(QWidget *pParent)
{
    QWidget *pQuestionnaire = new QWidget(pParent);
    pQuestionnaire->setObjectName("plainArea");
    pQuestionnaire->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    pQuestionnaire->layout()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    pQuestionnaire->layout()->setMargin(0);

    // Cabeçalho
    QLabel *pTitle = new QLabel("Por favor, responda às perguntas a seguir.", pQuestionnaire);
    pTitle->setObjectName("headerTitle");
    pQuestionnaire->layout()->addWidget(pTitle);

    QFrame *pLine = new QFrame(pQuestionnaire);
    pLine->setFrameStyle(QFrame::HLine);
    pLine->setLineWidth(4);
    pQuestionnaire->layout()->addWidget(pLine);
    static_cast<QBoxLayout*>(pQuestionnaire->layout())->addSpacing(10);

    // Scroll Area
    QScrollArea *pScroll = new QScrollArea(pQuestionnaire);
    pScroll->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    pScroll->setObjectName("plainArea");
    pScroll->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    pQuestionnaire->layout()->addWidget(pScroll);

    QWidget *pArea = new QWidget(pQuestionnaire);
    pArea->setObjectName("plainArea");
    pArea->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    pArea->layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);
    pArea->layout()->setMargin(0);

    pScroll->setWidget(pArea);
    pScroll->setWidgetResizable(true);

    // Questões
    QStringList lFruits = {
        "Abacate", "Amora", "Ameixa", "Acerola", "Abacaxi", "Açaí",
        "Banana", "Bacuri", "Buriti", "Butiá", "Bacaba", "Carambola",
        "Cajá", "Caju", "Cereja", "Cacau", "Caqui", "Cupuaçu", "Damasco",
        "Figo", "Framboesa", "Fruta Pão", "Graviola", "Goiaba", "Goiaba Branca",
        "Groselha", "Guaraná", "Grumixama", "Guariroba", "Ingá", "Ibapó",
        "Itu", "Ingá Dedo", "Ingá Branco", "Jaca", "Jabuticaba", "Jambo",
        "Jenipapo", "Jatobá", "Kiwi", "Laranja", "Limão", "Lima Doce",
        "Lixia", "Melancia", "Mamão", "Melão", "Maracujá", "Manga",
        "Macadâmia", "Maçã", "Mangaba", "Mexerica", "Nectarina", "Noz",
        "Nêspera", "Olho-De-Boi", "Pera", "Pêssego", "Pitaya", "Pitanga",
        "Pinha", "Pinhão", "Pitomba", "Pocã", "Quina", "Rabutan", "Romã",
        "Sapoti", "Sapucaia", "Salok", "Saputá", "Tangerina", "Tomate",
        "Tamarindo", "Toranja", "Taiúva", "Uva", "Uxi", "Uvaia", "Umbu",
        "Veludo", "Wampi", "Xixá"
    };

    QStringList lOptions = { "detesto", "gosto pouco", "gosto", "gosto muito", "adoro" };

    for(int i = 0; i < lFruits.size(); i++)
    {
        QWidget *pRow = new QWidget(pQuestionnaire);
        pArea->layout()->addWidget(pRow);

        if(i % 2)
            pRow->setObjectName("highlightedrow");

        pRow->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
        QLabel *pQuestion = new QLabel(QString("%1 - Você gosta de %2?").arg(i+1).arg(lFruits.at(i)), pRow);
        pQuestion->setObjectName("questionTitle");
        pRow->layout()->addWidget(pQuestion);

        QWidget *pOptions = new QWidget(pRow);
        pRow->layout()->addWidget(pOptions);
        pOptions->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());
        pOptions->layout()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);

        static_cast<QBoxLayout*>(pOptions->layout())->addSpacing(60);
        foreach(QString sOption, lOptions)
        {
            QRadioButton *pButton = new QRadioButton(sOption, pOptions);
            pButton->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
            pButton->setObjectName("optionTitle");
            pOptions->layout()->addWidget(pButton);
            static_cast<QBoxLayout*>(pOptions->layout())->addSpacing(20);
        }
    }

    return pQuestionnaire;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication oApp(argc, argv);

    QWidget *pWindow = new QWidget();
    pWindow->setObjectName("plainArea");
    pWindow->setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET);
    pWindow->setWindowTitle("MCVE para o SOPT");

    pWindow->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    pWindow->layout()->addWidget(createQuestionnaire(pWindow));
    pWindow->layout()->setMargin(0);

    pWindow->show();
    pWindow->resize(800, 600);
    return oApp.exec();
}
```